# Celery - Read unstructured message from queue

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, kombu

I'm writing a Django application and I want to read messages from rabbitMQ and apply some changes into my database. My problem is the producer in not using celery and I get an error from celery because the message is invalid. The error is:

```
[2017-02-16 08:31:11,416: WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message.  Wrong destination?!?

The full contents of the message body was: body: {'value': '4', 'type': 'edit', 'rate': 1} (39b)
```

How can I handle it?
I have also tried [kombu](https://github.com/celery/kombu) but the problem is it's not as easy as celery; It doesn't work in the background so it is hard to be integrated with Django app.